# Functions in App.js not showing up in .jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

I have a react website and have a jsx file that is trying to call some functions I defined in my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import function1 from './App.js'
import function2 from './App.js'
import function3 from './App.js'

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          {function1() ? function2(): function3()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I then have an App.js file that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const function1 = () => { 
        return booleanvalue
    }
    const function2 = () => { 
        return (<button onClick={...} ... </button>)
    }
    const function3 = () => { 
        return (<button onClick={...} ... </button>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

But nothing shows up from the jsx file. I tried exporting these functions at the end but this also doesn't do anything. Is there any way I can export these local functions within my App() or call them because I am already exporting App?

Comment: You might want to look into how to export functions in JavaScript. How will App.js know what functions to export ? You are not telling JavaScript to export function. You either do `export default function1` or you do `export {function1, function2, function3} `. Might want to read up on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I already tried exporting, so this comment is not very helpful. I specifically would like to know how to export functions from a larger function to another file in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css'
    export const function1 = () => { 
        return booleanvalue
    }

export const function2 = () => { 
        return (<button onClick={...} ... </button>)
    }

    export const function3 = () => { 
        return (<button onClick={...} ... </button>)
    }

export function App() {



}

export {App, function, function2, function3 }
```

This is how you export functions, but if you want React components then your component should start with a capital character.